# Segmentation fault (core dumped) after adding an array inside a struct

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I'm trying to add an array called `shape` inside a struct but once I add it and try to access the member `values`, it produces a segmentation fault. If I remove it, the program works perfectly.

This is the struct definition:

```
struct coo_matrix{
    int nnz;
    int shape[2];
    int * rows;
    int * columns;
    int * values;
};
typedef struct coo_matrix * COOMatrix;
```

This is the function where I try to access `values`:

```
COOMatrix coo_matrix_create(int m, int sparse_matrix[][m]){
    ...
    COOMatrix coo;
    coo = malloc(sizeof(COOMatrix));
    coo->rows = malloc(n * m * sizeof(int));
    coo->columns = malloc(n * m * sizeof(int));
    coo->values = malloc(n * m * sizeof(int));
    ....
    ....
            coo->rows[k] = i;
            coo->columns[k] = j;
            coo->values[k] = sparse_matrix[i][j]; // see Note
    ....
    return coo;
}
```

**Note**: Once I add shape, this line produces a segmentation fault.

PS: No need to say I am not very familiar with C, I learned other languages before I ever touched C recently.

Comment: `COOMatrix` and `coo_matrix` are different things. you haven't shown any `typedef`s here.

Comment: @sjsam I forgot to include it in my question. Added

Comment: `typdef`ing pointers is bound to get you into trouble.

Comment: @DavidBowling Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Why are you using `sizeof(COOMatrix)` in all allocations? You need `sizeof(struct coo_matrix)`, or better, `sizeof *coo` for the first allocation.

Comment: I saw it on a book/university guide and they were allocating memory in that same way. No, checked again and it was a copy/paste mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple of problems in that code.  First, you declare your COOMatrix as a pointer but then confuse things by using it to get the size of the underlying struct.  Secondly, you declare rows, columns and values as pointers to ints but then allocate them using sizeof(COOMatrix).  Because of the first error, the second might actually work depending on the machine but isn't what you want.  So

```
struct coo_matrix{
...
};
typedef struct coo_matrix COOMatrix;
COOMatrix *coo_matrix_create(int m, int sparse_matrix[][m]){
    ...
    COOMatrix *coo;
    coo = malloc(sizeof(COOMatrix));
    coo->rows = malloc(n * m * sizeof(int));
    coo->columns = malloc(n * m * sizeof(int));
    coo->values = malloc(n * m * sizeof(int));
    ....
    ....
            coo->rows[k] = i;
            coo->columns[k] = j;
            coo->values[k] = sparse_matrix[i][j]; // see Note
    ....
    return coo;
}
```

Should be closer

Comment: You are right about `sizeof`. It was a copy/paste mistake *facepalm*. I guess I should go to sleep for a while

Comment: Better to use `malloc(sizeof(int) * n * m)`, or better yet, `malloc(sizeof *coo->rows * n * m)` to reduce risk of potential integer overflow problems, i.e., to ensure that math is done with `size_t` types.

Comment: @DavidBowling That is a really nice tip!